# Parameterize an implicit equation

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebraic-geometry

I am trying to parameterize the following implicit equation so that I can sketch it.

***$x^2+y^2=1+4.5\sin^2(xy)$***

However, I am having problems with parameterizing the equation because of the $xy$ and inside the sine function.

The usual way would be to use the trigonometric identity $sin^2(x)+cos^2(x)=1$ when trying to parameterize a equation. For example if we would parameterize $x^2+y^2=1$. Then I would just put $x=rcos(\theta)$ and that would give me $y=rsin(\theta)$.

I have tried to put $x=arcsin^2(t)$ to get rid of the sine function and then solve for $y$. However, I dont get the answer that I want to be able to sketch it.

How would one approach this equation to find an appropriate parameterization?

Comment: Can't help you with a parameterization, but if all you want to do is see it, here's a sketch (along with a unit circle) at desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/z0q9oodqtl

Comment: Where does the problem come from?

Comment: Separated parametrizations do not always exist. This is one of those cases.  Instead, you write your equation in implicit form, $$x^2 + y^2 - 1 - \frac{9}{2}\left(\sin(x y)\right)^2 = x^2 + y^2 - 1 - \frac{9}{4}\left(1 - \cos(2 x y)\right) = 0$$ and solve for each $y$ separately, fixing $x$. (The right side is from double-angle formula, and is very useful form because $\cos(-z) = \cos(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{R}$.) For example, $x = 0$ the equation becomes $y^2 - 1 = 0$; at $x = \pm 1$ it becomes $y^2 + \frac{9}{4}\left(\cos(2 y) - 1\right) = 0$, and so on.